# Rails UJS - Can't get jquery to trigger after first action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ujs

In my show.html.haml view, I have a form where the user's able to change a few settings. I've just updated to use Rails UJS and, when my users change a drop-down menu, they see the jquery shizzle doing it's thing.

All I've really done in the show.js file is refresh the partial the form sits in and flash an error message.

The problem is that once it's been updated once, the jquery drop-down select doesn't work. I figured this was because it's rendering the update.js view - I therefore included this file. However, still nothing happens and I get no errors in the logs.

In show.html.haml I have (simplified):

```
#show_form
  = render "show"
```

My show partial contains:

```
= semantic_form_for @product_order, :remote => true do |f| 
  = f.select :shipping_method, options_for_select(ProductOrder::Couriers, :selected => @product_order.shipping_method)
```

My show.js.erb and update.js.erb contain:

```
$("#show_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("show")) %>");
$("#status_banner").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
$("#status_banner").html("<h2>ORDER STATUS: <%= (@product_order.state.titlecase) %></h2>");
$("#status_banner").removeClass("alert").addClass("alert <%= (@product_class) %>");
```

In my product_order.js.coffee I have this:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#dropdown_select").change ->
    $(this).closest("form").submit()
    $(this).serialize()
    null
    "script"
    false
```

Like I said, the first action works but fails after the first update. My controller update action is a little bulky but I have made sure I have format.js included. I've also tried putting respond_to :js at the top of my controller.

Am I doing this wrong or is there a simple fix that I'm unable to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that after you refresh the form, your js isn't firing because technically its a new element in the DOM. You'd need to use jquery event binding like so:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#dropdown_select").on "change", ->
    $(this).closest("form").submit()
    $(this).serialize()
    null
    "script"
    false
```

Comment: I see what you mean and have tried but it's still not firing. Have checked and double checked and get nothing in the logs. S

Comment: What I've also noticed is my drop-down doesn't render correctly after the first update. Am using chosen to make it pretty - after the refresh, I get a standard menu.

Comment: Well, the styling for the select shouldn't change unless the library you're using uses javascript to change it, then however it's a library issue on their part. Also, try commenting out the `$(this).serialize()` and everything below it and then try running it again.

Comment: Chosen relies on JS and it seems to be losing and javascript that was once included. I've tried as suggested without success.

Comment: Then there must be something else conflicting with your code somewhere. In a basic rails app, the above works for me.

Comment: Let me run through my controller action again. I should be fine with respond_to :js in my update action right?

Comment: yeah, that'll render the js file that is named the same as your action. Are you sure there's no other js that's conflicting with this and making the event binding not work? Are you sure the select that's rendered after the refresh has the id of dropdown_select still?

Comment: Have checked the id is intact - was going to change to a class instead... Just about to try. I'm also going to remove everyone other js file from my application manifest. Failing that, I'll remove all the xs from my controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19841/discussion-between-magicmarkker-and-simonmorley)

Comment: Have marked this as solved. Thanks for the help and for proving I wasn't on the wrong path. Having removed the refresh from update, it's working ok. Not perfect yet but can deal with that later. S